# Tracking performance in a SPA

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

We are rebuilding an existing JSP web application using AngularJS.  In our existing application we use the page load time metrics extensively.

With the SPA there are no real page load times.  How can we track user experience of performance through GA in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how long something takes you can use [User Timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings) - this somewhat resembles event tracking, only you pass a duration as value parameter (i.e. you need to start a timer when your thing starts, stop if when it's ready and the time measured is the value for the user timing):

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'timing',
  timingCategory: 'SPA Content change',
  timingVar: 'load',
  timingValue: 100
});
```